# Magento product watermarks are not appearing transparent - any ideas?

Tags: php, magento, png, transparency, photoshop

I have a Magento ver. 1.3.3.0 install, I am having a problem with the transparency of product watermarks.
The watermark is a .png file but when it is viewed on the product it loses its transparency and has a solid white background. The products on the shop are a wildlife artists paintings so this is really spoiling the artwork.

Has anyone experienced this with 1.3.3.0? Upgrading at this stage is not really an option as the site needs to go live soon.

Regards

Dan

Comment: sounds like a png problem and not magneto, check your css to

Comment: Hmm, Im not sure it is, It does the same with a .gif. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it only happens with PNG files and you have guaranteed that the original has the proper transparency then are you viewing the page in Internet Explorer?

Older versions of Internet Explorer don't properly render PNG alpha values, meaning that PNG transparency doesn't work. There are multiple javascript fixes for it online.

If it happens in Chrome/Firefox/Safari then post your CSS, as there may be a line affecting the alpha transparency of PNG files.

Comment: This was about server side image mixing, not client side

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=6020

known bug with your version - if you paste the 1.3.2.1 version of lib/varien/image/adapter/Gd2.php into your 1.3.1 version of Magento may be a quick fix.  Be sure and make a backup before overwriting the file, and I would suggest keeping a copy to rename upon performing a full upgrade.

Comment: Hi Boomer thanks for your contribution, however, I am using version 1.3.3.0 not 1.3.1? I tried it anyway to no avail. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: You can try and delete everything under media/watermarks and try different variants of PNG files, even some online would be good to test to determine if its actually Magento, the file or GD itself.  Hope this helps.